# Codeigniter how to use get_where/or_where together to return a result_array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get a `result_array()` from a database which two columns must return true, and vise-versa so I decided to use `or_where` but my code is returning `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::or_where()` error, any advice how can achieve this?

I am using below code on inside my CI_Model.

```
public function check_request($userid, $senderid){
     $query = $this->db->get_where('connection',array('user_id' => $userid, 'sender_id' => $senderid));
     $query = $this->db->or_where('connection',array('sender_id' => $userid, 'user_id' => $senderid));
     return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: plz update question and show where are you using this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Below:

```
public function check_request($userid, $senderid){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->where("(user_id = '$userid' AND sender_id = '$senderid') 
               OR (sender_id='$userid' AND user_id = '$senderid')");
   $query = $this->db->get('connection');
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Did you check this? @KaoriYui

Comment: Got a error `Error Number: 1064` (`SELECT * FROM 14, `b7vlg0tnd174819`) my table name is connection its seems its selecting from the array instead.

Comment: did you check now?

Comment: what you are getting in  `echo $this->db->last_query(); die;`

Comment: After i validation the query is correct, i just need to simulate two different user id, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this. Before some day same issue i got. and i had try like this.

```
$query =  $this->db->select('*')
           ->where("(user_id = '$userid' AND sender_id = '$senderid') OR (user_id = '$senderid' AND sender_id = '$userid')")
         ->get('connection');

 return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Can you please check edited ans. I have made changes.

Comment: My error now is `Error Number: 1054` Unknown column 'b7vlg0tnd174819' in 'where clause'` my column is user_id and sender_id.

Comment: @shefali may be you missed "from" clause